IBM X3400 M3 server I have locked myself out of BIOS
I have re-built my machine to use NVME drive for my openSUSE Leap15.5 system.  I could not find out at the time how to boot from NVME so I used a small partition "stolen" from my main RAID array which is mainly used for data so that I could put the efi and boot files on that partition.
On a recent re-boot the efi boot files have given me a warning post message and I cannot boot my system.  In trying to get a rescue system to run in efi mode I messed up the BIOS and am now locked out.  No video (there was is external video card).  The internal display was turned off in the BIOS.
I have attached a VGA display and I get a few lines and then the system wants to use UEFI but alas my system will only know about the efi files when it reads them because the BIOS is perhaps too old for UEFI?  So after a few seconds trying it goes to sleep and it will not boot from an USB live distro either.
Grateful for anybody who can advise.  The machines are very old now but running well for their purpose until I cocked one up so now we only have one backup machine.
I would like to tag as bios reset but may need your advice please

System x3400 M3 reach end of Service Life on December 31, 2020

the efi boot files have given me a warning post message and I cannot boot my system. That sounds more like cannot find boot device.

Hi, my post is not quite accurate.  I had the post warning and then tried to boot to live system rescue. I could not find how to boot to efi rescue, the rescue always boots to legacy.  That was when I messed up the BIOS so now the BIOS is looking foir UEFI at startup after loading kernel, cannot find uefi and goes to sleep without booting.  Thanks for the reply.  Is there any hardware reset on the mobo as I am now stuffed!

I have the manual for this server and am looking at the various reset options now. I note that Romeo Ninov has advised the machine has reached eol but does anybody know what are the last available firmware upgrades.  If it was supported up to 2020 there should be an UEFI BIOS available.  My system was last upgraded in 2019 but if it has an UEFI bios I regret I do not know how to enable it.  This is one reason why I have locked myself out because the system at present now expects it.  Any ideas?
